# Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\user\.android\debug.keystore": Integrity check failed in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, debugging

I just opened flutter default app and ran the code. It showed this error. I am not able to understand what needs to be done.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjD4T.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Delete any old Debug key and create a new one. run this code to create a new debug key.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\yourusernamehere\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```